# How to specify Python library dependencies not on Pypi in package requirements

Tags: python, dependencies

My Python package requires the os module to work. I've added it to my setup.py
`install_requires=['os']`
and imported it into my module. However, it still isn't being imported. I know that packages not on PyPi require a dependency link, but what about packages that are part of the Python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import any packages that are in the python library by default with a simple import statement. They don't need to be installed by any dependency tool. Usage should look like this.

```
import os

os.path.exists("some_path")
```

More examples can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html).

Comment: Oh you're right, I just checked. I think the error has to do with dotenv() and os.getenv() not being able to load my environment variables. Not sure why that's the case since I checked if os and dotenv is installed, and it is.

Comment: Haha I'm dumb. I was using load_dotenv() with no parameters before I packaged my Python script, which worked. For some reason, the python package needed '.env' to be passed as a param to work.